# Does anyone recognize this markup language from the Google Admin Console?

Tags: console, markup

If you make specific cURL requests to various pages in the Google Admin Console, it's possible to get specific formatted pieces of data. Most of it comes back in a markup language that I don't recognize.

Does anyone out there know what this is?

Here's an example:

[,"12","Email",[[,"123k8xu49asdasd;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1","This user has full administrative rights for Email",1,,,"Email;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1"] ] ] ,[,"190","Mobile",[[,"123282asdasd;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1","This user has full administrative rights for Mobile",1,,,"Mobile;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1"] ]

I went through the markup language list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_document_markup_languages and did not find a match.

Comment: this looks like JavaScript array definition

Comment: What does the `Content-Type` HTTP header say ? I'd guess application/json  or some variant of [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I can easily use this code as a JavaScript array - try this example (added a few square brackets). These snippets are most likely used with AJAX requests

```
<script>
var ar = [[,"12","Email",[[,"123k8xu49asdasd;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1","This user has full administrative rights for Email",1,,,"Email;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1"] ] ] ,[,"190","Mobile",[[,"123282asdasd;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1","This user has full administrative rights for Mobile",1,,,"Mobile;;;APP_ADMIN;;;1"] ] ]];
alert(ar[0][3][0][1]);
</script>
```